# How to perform load testing for many users?

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I am new to `jmeter`, I am trying to do load testing for 20 users for the below scenario but facing some issues

There are 3 sequential url, in the first url.. request will be send and in the 3rd url the response message (response is processed) will be obtained.
So to obtain the response message we have to refresh the 3rd url i.e 3rd url will be refreshed until we get a response message like response is processed. If I am doing a load testing for 3 users. for first user the response message may be obtained at 3rd time refresh of 3rd url and for 2nd user it may be obtained at 5th time refresh similarly for 3rd user it may be obtained at 8th or 10th time  refresh of 3rd url so we will be getting the response message at any `n'th` refresh of 3rd url.

On each HTTP request the sample time is calculated however i need to calculate how long for 1 user it takes i.e timetaken ,starting from the 1st request until the response message is obtained in 3rd url

There are 2 issues:

1. I am unaware of how can I set a condition to click on the 3rd url until response message is obtained.
2. How can I get the timetaken for 1 user for 3 url i.e from sending request in 1st url to obtaining response message in 3rd url instead of sample time for each url (http request)

Can somebody please help me with this issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your "3rd url" request under [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and specify the condition in the way so the request will loop until response matches your expectations
2. You can measure the whole sequence execution time by putting all 3 requests under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

   [image: JMeter While Controller Test Plan Outline]